# Is there a way to refine the cutout in the original image when using remove background in Adobe Express?

Tags: untagged

In Adobe Express, there's an auto remove background functionality. However, the result most of the time isn't good enough, so there's a need to further manually refine the cutout, however for some reason Adobe Express thinks it's a good idea to put the result of the auto cutout into a new blank image with a complete different resolution and scale it randomly for manual refinement. Is there a way to configure Adobe Express so that the manual refinement of the cutout can be done in the original image?

Comment: @Scott Adobe Express is https://apps.apple.com/us/app/adobe-express-graphic-design/id1051937863 and Photoshop Express is https://apps.apple.com/us/app/photoshop-express-photo-editor/id331975235. They are two completely different apps. Not sure why you changed the original question from Adobe Express to Photoshop Express ...

Comment: Apologies.. `:)` I had not heard of "Adobe Express".  I know of Spark and Post.. but just wasn't aware of the umbrella name they all now fall under. And the question was tagged with Photoshop.. so I made a leap. I've rolled back the question and added Adobe Express and Spark tags. (Clearly we don't get a lot of questions here for either. But they are welcome `:)` )

Comment: @Scott - it's Adobe's "one-touch" photo app for Android and iOS. To be honest, the whole point of it is not to refine anything, but to get a result with just a few taps at most.  Not sure it's really advanced enough for what the OP is looking for. Not something I would be likely to use myself - at least not for any serious graphic design work.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Express is essentially a limited version of photoshop, so refining is limited as well.  You need to use Photoshop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the Senior Community Relationship Manager for Adobe Express.

I'm sure this is too late to respond, but we now have an erase and restore tool with a quick selection and circle brush :) I hope you find it useful!